# Find the Langitude and Longitude of the centre point of a circle given a point on the circumference.

Tags: circles, pi

I couldn't find a similar question!

Given I have the latitude and longitude (x,y) of a point on the circumference of a circle, and I  want the circumference to be 1000m. An example of a lat lang I have is

```
lat="52.4245085" lon="-1.9441316"
```

(please correct the below if wrong)
I got

```
diameter = 1000/pi
radius = diameter/2
```

How do I find the lang and lat of the centre point on my circle? I would like this point to be a plottable point on the earths surface.  I am aware I probably need to use the radius of the earth if I am to scale this which is 6 378.1km.

Would really appreciate any help or guidance on this.

As you can probably tell my maths knowledge isn't great, so if you could try and keep your answers simple I would be very really thankful.

edit: I understand that there are many possible solutions. I am trying to find just one circle, I understand there is not simply one unique one. If I also have a bearing (b) does this make a solution possible? The circle should run flat on the earth.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear. Latitude and longitude describe the location of a point on a *sphere*, not just a circle.

Comment: Even in the form lat="52.4245085" lon="-1.9441316" ?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What do you know about your circle? Does it run on the surface of the earth? Does it run horizontally, vertically, otherwise?

Comment: I'm sorry as I say my maths isn't great, please ask the necessary questions and I'll update my post. Yes I would like it to run on the surface of the earth. What do you mean by horizontally or vertically?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you have insufficient data. By just one point, there's no unique circle that runs through it. The circle could stay on the same longitude, on the same latitude, or something else, they could all go through your point $(x,y)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just trying to find a circle, not a unique one. Would adding a bearing or something help?

Comment: All right, that changes the question, and makes it possible. There's still more ways to do, I'll see if I can work one out in an answer

Comment: Really appreciate the help, let me update my question.

Comment: Sorry, the question is harder than I thought, but also, are you aware that the center lies inside the earth, and not on the surface. I think you'd have to look at projections of maps first, but that your question becomes harder and harder. Maybe someone else will have a better approach to this, but I think it's harder than you'd expect on first sight.

Comment: I'd like to generate a point on the centre of the earth if possible. I thought it might be tough which is why I came to the experts :)!